# At most one divisor in $[\sqrt{n},\sqrt{n}+\sqrt[4]{n}]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In one math book I'm reading there was the following problem, given as an exercise:

> For any $n\in\Bbb N$ there is at most one divisor of $n$ in the interval $[\sqrt{n},\sqrt{n}+\sqrt[4]{n}]$.

I was unable to solve this problem myself, and author didn't leave any hint for this problem (which, presumably, means that it's quite simple).

Friend of mine has found a proof which uses AM-GM inequality, but I'm quite certain there is a proof avoiding it, because the convention in this book appears to be that every exercise can be solved only using methods already covered in earlier chapters, and this exercise is at the end of a chapter about divisibility (gcd, prime numbers and so on).

Is anyone aware of, or can come up with, such a solution of this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I thought it might be a good idea to post the solution my friend came up with. So here it is:

Suppose we have two distinct divisors in the interval in question, and let $d$ be their GCD. Write these divisors as $da,db$, so that $gcd(a,b)=1$. Wlog, let $a<b$. Because $\sqrt{n}\leq da<db\leq\sqrt{n}+\sqrt[4]{n}$, we know that $d\leq\sqrt[4]{n}$.

Because $da\mid n,db\mid n$, we get $dab=lcm(da,db)\mid n$. Write $n=dabk$. Because $db>da\geq\sqrt{n}$ we get $dadb>n=dabk$, so $d>k$.

From $a<b$ we know that $a\leq b-1$, similarly we know from $k<d$ that $k\leq d$. So $n=dabk\leq d(d-1)b(b-1)<(d-1/2)^2(b-1/2)^2$ (first use of AM-GM). We can also find $\sqrt{(b-1/2)(d-1/2)}\leq(b-1/2+d-1/2)/2=b/2+d/2-1/2$ (second use of AM-GM).

From last two inequalities we can find $\sqrt{n}+\sqrt[4]{n}<(b-1/2)(d-1/2)+b/2+d/2-1/2=bd-1/4<bd$, contradicting assumption that $bd\leq\sqrt{n}+\sqrt[4]{n}$.

I know that, as we just use AM-GM for two numbers we can easily prove the inequalities other way, but I feel like it's a bit of cheating here.

Comment: There's more to this than meets the eye - 20 for example provides a near-counter example with 4 and 5.

Comment: Probably it would be too hard for me but I would like to know what book you were reading if possible, thanks

Comment: @DanielD. It's an olympiad math preparation book by a Polish author, written in Polish. If you care for the details, I can find them for you.

Comment: Don't worry I don't think I would be able to learn polish but if a translation ever exists please let me know sounds like a fun book, thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $x\in \mathbb{R}$ is positive and $\sqrt{n} - x$ is an integer divisor of $n$. Now, consider $$\frac{n}{\sqrt{n} - x -1} - \frac{n}{\sqrt{n} - x}.$$ I claim that this is a little bit more than $1$. Not much more for small $x$, but a little. And, as we decrease the first denominator in steps of $1$, the difference keeps increasing by just a little more than $1$ at each step. For ${\sqrt{n} - x -k}$ to be a divisor, we need these little bits to add to some integer. At the very least, we need them to add to $1$ or more. That is, it is necessary that $$f(x, y) = \frac{n}{\sqrt{n} - y} - \frac{n}{\sqrt{n} - x} -(y - x) \geq 1$$ for $\sqrt{n} - x$ and $\sqrt{n} - y$ to be integer divisors of $n$ with $0\leq x<y$. Some calculus will tell you that $f$ increases as $x$ goes to $0$ and as $y$ increases.

Let $y_0$ be such that $$f(0, y_0) = \frac{n}{\sqrt{n} - y_0} - \sqrt{n} - y_0 = 1.$$ Therefore$$y_0^2 +y_0 -\sqrt{n} = 0$$ and $$ y_0= -\frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{1}{4} + \sqrt{n}} > -\frac{1}{2} + \sqrt[4]{n}$$ and finally $$\frac{n}{\sqrt{n} - y_0} = 1 + \sqrt{n} + y_0 > \frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{n} + \sqrt[4]{n}.$$ We conclude that there isn't enough space in the interval $[\sqrt{n}, \sqrt{n} + \sqrt[4]{n}]$ to get the increase in $f$ that is a necessary condition for there being two divisors.

Comment: I'm not really a fan of this solution, because it uses "some calculus", which is beyond the methods discussed in the book, but I guess I didn't exactly specify what I think is and isn't allowed. If no one posts a better solution, I'll reward you the bounty.

Comment: I largely agree with you, and although you could show those with just some algebra, there's an ugliness about it that is very obvious. It is quite a sharp result though, for instance $93636 = 306^2$, with divisor $324$. $324-306/\sqrt{306} = 1.02$. That's not much leeway, and in my experience sharp results have ugly or very tricky proofs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an argument that needs some justification of the assumptions that you want the factors to be close and $b,c$ to be a big as possible, but is quite elementary.

Let the factors be $ab, (a+1)b$, so $b$ is their GCD. Let $n=a(a+1)bc$.  The $a+1$ comes from the fact that you want the factors to be as close as possible.  Then we can't have $\sqrt n=ab$ because we would have $n=a^2b^2$ and $(a+1)b$ can't be a factor, so $\sqrt n \lt ab$  or $a^2bc+abc \lt a^2b^2.$  This forces $c \lt b$  From the difference of the factors ($b$) being less than the fourth root of $n$ we get $b^4 \lt a^2bc+abc \lt a^2b^2+ab^2$, which requires $b \lt a$

A little playing shows we want $b,c$ to be as large as possible to get close, so let $b=a-1,c=a-2$ then $n=(a+1)a(a-1)(a-2)=a^4-2a^3-a^2+2a$.  The factors are $a(a-1)$ and $(a+1)(a-1)=a^2-1$  Then $\sqrt n \lt a(a-1)-1, \sqrt[4]n \lt a, \text { and } \sqrt n +\sqrt[4]n \lt a^2-1$, which was the second factor.

Comment: I don't see any way to formalize your (not really justified) assumptions on $a,b,c$, so I am not going to take this as valid solution, but this still is an interesting approach.

Comment: I didn't make any assumptions about $a$, but I did assume the second factor was $(a+1)b,$ not $(a+2)b$.  I think you can show that $(a+1)b$ will always work if $(a+2)$ does.  As I said, choosing $b,c$ as large as possible was motivated by playing with a spreadsheet and seeing that you get as close as possible when they are large.  Again, I think you can show that if a smaller $b$ or $c$ works then the one I called out does, too.  Then when this fails you are done.

Comment: I don't really see what you mean with "(a+1)b will always work if (a+2) does". If you have two divisors of $15$, namely $3,5$, then you can write them as $ab,(a+2)b$ for $a=3,b=1$, and I don't see in what way $(a+1)b=4$ is supposed to work.

Comment: What I mean is that if you can find an $n$ satisfying the requirement with factors $ab, (a+2)b$ (and $b$ needs to be odd here), you can find an $n'$ that uses factors $ab, (a+1)b$  This is because the fourth root increases slowly with $n$

Answer (score 0):

This argument uses the notation above, and still uses the AM-GM inequality in one step:

$k\le d-1 \text{ and } a\le b-1\implies bd-ka\ge bd-(d-1)(b-1)=b+d-1,$ so

$\displaystyle b+d-1\ge a+d\ge2\sqrt{ad}\ge2\sqrt[4]{n}\implies \frac{bd(b+d-1)}{2bd}\ge\sqrt[4]{n}\implies\frac{bd(bd-ka)}{2bd}\ge\sqrt[4]{n}\implies$

$\displaystyle bd-\sqrt{n}=\frac{b^2 d^2-n}{bd+\sqrt{n}}=\frac{bd(bd-ka)}{bd+\sqrt{n}}>\frac{bd(bd-ka)}{2bd}\ge\sqrt[4]{n}\implies bd>\sqrt{n}+\sqrt[4]{n}$,

which gives a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Using the notation given by the OP, we have that

$(a^2-bd)^2+a^2(b^2-a^2)>0\implies a^4-2a^2bd+b^2d^2+a^2b^2-a^4>0\implies b^2[d^2+a^2]>2a^2bd$,

so $\;b^2[a^2+ad+d^2]>2a^2bd+b^2ad>2a^2bd+a^3d\implies$

$\;\;\;\;b^2[a^2+2ad+d^2]>2a^2bd+ab^2d+a^3d=ad[a^2+2ab+b^2]\implies$

$\;\;\;\;b^2(a+d)^2>ad(a+b)^2\implies b(a+d)>(a+b)\sqrt{ad}\implies \color{blue}{bd(a+d)>(bd+ad)\sqrt{ad}}$.

Then $d-1\ge k \text{ and } b-1\ge a\implies bd-ka\ge bd-(d-1)(b-1)=b+d-1\ge a+d$,

so$\displaystyle\;\;\; \color{blue}{bd-\sqrt{n}=\frac{b^2d^2-n}{bd+\sqrt{n}}=\frac{bd(bd-ak)}{bd+\sqrt{n}}>\frac{bd(a+d)}{bd+ad}>\sqrt{ad}>\sqrt[4]{n}}$.

Therefore $bd>\sqrt{n}+\sqrt[4]{n}$, which gives a contradiction.